# How can I delimit a field in SQL and create separate rows from that field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field in SQL Server that can sometimes contain text separated by Pipe like this:

```
COLOUR
Red
Blue|Red|Yellow
Green|White
Yellow
```

And I want to create this:

```
COLOUR          SUBCOLOUR
Red             Red
Blue|Red|Yellow Blue
Blue|Red|Yellow Red
Blue|Red|Yellow Yellow
Green|White     Green
Green|White     White
Yellow          Yellow
```

Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you "want to create this" where?  Are you asking how to create a ***new table*** for normalizing the pipe delimited data?  Adding a column to the existing table for some reason? in a select statement only? please elaborate

Comment: I want to create a new table from the existing data that is in the format of the second table above.

Comment: @wilsonm2 may be the answer will be matching your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using split function we can achieve the desired result set

```
 declare @t table (Colour  varchar(50))
    insert into @t (Colour)
    values 
    ('Red'),
    ('Blue|Red|Yellow'),
    ('Green|White'),
    ('Yellow')



 ;with cte as (
    SELECT  Colour As Colour ,
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SubColour  
     FROM  (SELECT Colour,
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Colour], '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
         FROM  @t) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))

         select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but with comments. Uses variables and a cursor, so would only recommend if this is not a large table and you are only doing this once. I would be happy to provide more explanation if this doesn't work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable (Colour varchar(50),SubColour varchar(50))   

SELECT Colour, LEN(Colour) - LEN(REPLACE(Colour,'|','')) AS delimCount
INTO #temp FROM [ColourTable]

DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @delimLoc int
DECLARE @Colour varchar(50)
DECLARE @subColour varchar(50)
DECLARE ColourCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #temp;
OPEN ColourCursor;
```

Going row by row through the table

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

FETCH NEXT FROM ColourCursor INTO @Colour;
SET @i = 1
SET @delimLoc = 0
IF delimCount > 0

BEGIN
WHILE @i <= delimCount
```

The loop creates a subcolor going from the location of the last used '|' (or the beginning of the Colour Field if @i = 1)

```
BEGIN
SET @subColour = SUBSTRING(@Colour,@delimLoc+1,CHARINDEX(@Colour,'|',@delimLoc+1))
INSERT INTO NewTable VALUES (@Colour,@subColour)
SET @i = @i + 1
SET @delimLoc = @delimLoc + CHARINDEX(@Colour,'|',@delimLoc+1)
END

END

END

CLOSE ColourCursor
DEALLOCATE ColourCursor;
```

Comment: There are dozens of better options for splitting strings than a cursor. The performance of a cursor is very poor for this sort of thing. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Of course, the best option of all is for the OP to stop storing data that violates 1NF.

Comment: @wilsonm2 See these suggestions for better options than the one I posted. You might need to do a few adjustments if you want to include the original Colour field for each SubColour